# Obtain new columns of T/F values from list of lists using loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list of lists (sig_list) containing gene transcript IDs that have been deemed significant by three different models (sig_1, sig_2, sig_3):

```
sig_list <- list(sig_1=sig_1$ensembl_transcript_id, sig_2=sig_2$ensembl_transcript_id, sig_3=sig_3$ensembl_transcript_id)

lengths(sig_list)
sig_1 sig_2 sig_3 
684   479   270
```

I also have a 1-column dataframe (shared_trans) containing >3,000 transcript IDs from a publication.

```
head(shared_trans)
ensembl_transcript_id
<chr>
1   ENST00000000442         
2   ENST00000001008         
3   ENST00000001146         
4   ENST00000002596         
5   ENST00000003583         
6   ENST00000004531
```

I want to add one new column per list in sig_list with the values corresponding to TRUE if that list contains that transcript ID, or FALSE if it does not. Here's an example of what I got when I did this step-by-step instead of in a loop:

```
# Make example df
shared_trans_example <- shared_trans

# New column for every sig df
shared_trans_example$sig_1 <- shared_trans$ensembl_transcript_id %in% sig_1$ensembl_transcript_id
shared_trans_example$sig_2 <- shared_trans$ensembl_transcript_id %in% sig_2$ensembl_transcript_id
shared_trans_example$sig_3 <- shared_trans$ensembl_transcript_id %in% sig_3$ensembl_transcript_id

head(shared_trans_example)
ensembl_transcript_id
<chr>
sig_1
<lgl>
sig_2
<lgl>
sig_3
<lgl>
1   ENST00000000442 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
2   ENST00000001008 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
3   ENST00000001146 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   
4   ENST00000002596 TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
5   ENST00000003583 TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    
6   ENST00000004531 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

The problem is I have dozens of these models, and keep generating more, so I want to create a loop that adds new columns and T or F if the transcript is present in a given list. Here's what I have so far:

```
for (i in 1:length(sig_list)){
  shared_trans[,paste(i)] <- shared_trans$ensembl_transcript_id %in% i
}
```

When I do this, three columns (labeled "1", "2", "3") are added, but all values are "FALSE". I know from shared_trans_example that there should be at least 30 genes from each list that should be labeled "TRUE".  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: just a guess since the example is not reproducible, change inside the loop to something like `shared_trans[, sprintf('model_%s', names(sig_list)[i])] <- test$ensembl_transcript_id %in% sig_list[[ii]]`

Comment: 7 minutes has to be a record for receiving an answer that works! Thank you so much!

Comment: `merge(shared_trans, stack(sig_list), by.x = 'ensembl_transcript_id', by.y = 'value', all.x = TRUE)` then you can transform to TRUE/FALSE and pivot_wider